# Need to make multiple json object in single document in php

Tags: php, json

I have use this code to make `json` object

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($document = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $documents[] = $document;
        }
  }

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('documents'=>$documents));
```

It gives me single json in document like this

```
{"document":[{"document":{"id":"2","name":"test","pages":"name","img":"path","lines":"data"}]}
```

But i need

```
{"document":[{"document":{"id":"2","name":"test",pages":[{"img":"first img","lines":" <p>first line"}],pages":[{"img":"second img","lines":" <p>second line"}]}]}
```

Means in existing json need another json name pages which contain further img and lines.
How it can do?

Comment: *"Means in existing json need another json name pages which contain further img and lines. How it can do?"* I'm sorry, but that doesn't really make any sense in English. Can you try again (perhaps ask a colleague for help?).

Comment: So before using echo make your array like what you want..then echo it with json_encode..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do something like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($document = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $document["pages"] = array();
      $document["pages"][] = array("img" => "first img", "lines" => "first line");
      $document["pages"][] = array("img" => "second img", "lines" => "second line");
      $documents[] = $document;
    }
}
```

`json_encode(array('documents'=>$documents));` will return JSON object where each document will contain an array of pages with fields `img` and `lines`. Basically, you just need to create required structure in PHP, to get the same structure in JSON.

Above code should return something like this:

```
{"document": [{"document" : {"id":"2",
                             "name":"test", 
                             "pages":[{"img":"first img","lines":" <p>first line"},
                                     {"img":"second img","lines":" <p>second line"}]
                            }}
              ]}
```

Comment: I am newbie. How can i create php structure.

Comment: PHP code at the beginning of my answer. It shows how you can create a structure similar to what you need. How it should be created in your case - depends on your project.